# Prototype / class / public attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a constructor for a model (similar to Backbone model) which uses an instance of a store (e.g. MongoDB / Redis) which is passed to the model factory. Now inside the constructor for the model, I do

```
this.store = options.store;
```

Store is now available as `this.store` once I construct an instance with `var model = new Model()`.

Then I faced a situation when I my Model has "public" methods, e.g. `Model.find()` which will work without instantiating the model. But now because it's not been instantiated, functions inside Model can not access store by `this.store`.

What I did, is I started also adding store to the constructor itself `Model.store = options.store` which fixes the problem. But now store is exposed to anything that uses Model constructor and this is not desirable.

I am guessing I am doing something wrong. So I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You're conflating _instance_ methods/properties with class methods/properties. "Public" implies visibility, not ownership.

Comment: @MattBall I understand, but the question remains, is this the way to do it or am I completely wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown much code, so I can't really say. But it _sounds_ like there is a better way.

Comment: Is your goal to restrict the `find()` method to instances of `Model` (thereby getting access to the `this.store` variable) or making the `store` variable "static" so that `Model.find()` has access to it?

Comment: Did my answer help or am I completely missing your point?

Comment: @bmceldowney it does, your idea of having store in a closure makes sense although now that I think about it, from memory usage standpoint having store in every closure is an overhead compared to having store in prototype, although yes, now it's completely exposed if it's on prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you're saying correctly, then I think what you want is to allow for a "static" `find()` method on Model without exposing the `store` variable. Javascript doesn't really have a formal private scope for classes, but you can get what you want using closures. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/52FPy/

EDIT:
An updated fiddle to demonstrate various ways to expose/hide info using closures:
http://jsfiddle.net/52FPy/2/

Briefly:

```
var Model = function(){
    var store = 'this is a store';
    var Model = function(){

    }

    Model.find = function(){
        return store;
    }

    return Model;
}()
```

This will "hide" the `store` variable in the way you want.